# Segue to view controller crashing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in here? I've a small app that I'm designing, which is adding, editing and deleting user from my my core data. However, my application is crashing when i'm selecting a row, which is supposed to take me to the next viewController. 
The error is: 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'
It's failing in the prepare for segue function in this casting:             let contact:Contact = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Contact

So when I tap a row, it has to segue to the next view controller.

That's my code:

// Class ContactsTableViewController

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ContactsTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{

    // MARK: - Properties
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()


    // MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func toggleMe(sender: AnyObject) {
        UberSideBar.toggleWindow()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchedResultController = getFtechedResultController()
        fetchedResultController.delegate = self
        fetchedResultController.performFetch(nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        let numberOfSection = fetchedResultController.sections?.count
        return numberOfSection!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let numberOfinASection = fetchedResultController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
        return numberOfinASection!
    }

    // MARK: - Custom functions
    func getFtechedResultController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
        fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: taskFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: context!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        return fetchedResultController
    }

    func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest{
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contact")
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        return fetchRequest
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        // Refresh tableview to fetch all data
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ContactCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactcellTableViewCell
        let contact = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Contact
        println(contact.name)
        cell.nameLabel?.text = contact.name
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let managedObject: NSManagedObject = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
        context?.deleteObject(managedObject)
        context?.save(nil)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("editContact", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "editContact" {

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        let contactController: NewCategoryViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewCategoryViewController
        let contact:Contact = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Contact
        contactController.contact = contact

    }
}
```

}
and

```
   import UIKit
import CoreData


class NewCategoryViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var contact: Contact? = nil

    // initialize the core data context:
    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var imageHolder: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryField: UITextField!

    // MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func savebtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: context!)
        let newContact = Contact(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
            newContact.name = nameField.text
            newContact.email = emailField.text
            newContact.phone = phoneField.text
            //newContact.photo = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageHolder.image, 1)

        var error: NSError?

        context?.save(&error)

        if let errorSaving = error {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Couldn't save contact !!!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            nameField.text = ""
            emailField.text = ""
            phoneField.text = ""
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Contact added", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if contact != nil {
            nameField.text = contact?.name
            emailField.text = contact?.email
            phoneField.text = contact?.phone

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Apparently `sender` isn't a cell object, it is a tableview controller object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not cast the sender in prepareForSegue to ContactcellTableViewCell as it is of type ContactsTableViewController.

Instead of doing what you are doing, in order to obtain the indexPath, simply do

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
```

and remove this line:

```
let cell = sender as! ContactcellTableViewCell
```

Comment: Did it crash? If it did what was the exception? and where was it?

Comment: I tried this : override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "editContact" {
           
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
            let contactController: NewCategoryViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewCategoryViewController
            let contact:Contact = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Contact
            contactController.contact = contact
            
        }
    }
 but I'm receiving this error NSNumber is not a subtype of NSIndexPath

Comment: crashing here:  let contact:Contact = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Contact

Comment: you cannot do indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row.

Comment: if I do this let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow(), then it's crashing here             let contact:Contact = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Contact
 with the following error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: How is prepareForSegue triggered? Is it on selecting a row from the Table?

Comment: And also make sure you have connected the segue properly in the storyboard. That is, from your cell to the destination view controller.

Comment: thanks saw the mistake since for new and editing contact I'm using the same viewcontroller needed to segue from the tableview and from the add button

Comment: just a small issue, i'd like to change my next view controller navbar item button from add to done, when segue from selected row.

Comment: That should be easy. Just use the contactController you instantiated in prepareForSegue and set the title to whatever you want. example: contactController.addBarButton.title = "Done"

Comment: I've this:  destinationVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightAddBarButtonItem

it's displaying done, but it's breaking my code, because the doeEditing function, will be in the destinationVC, since it's going to save the fields when the user is done editing

Comment: I think creating a separate question for this would be better.

Comment: that's the link to it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32740801/set-navbar-item-button-to-new-title