# Set navbar item button to new title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

Good day. I'm facing a weird issue, I'd like to set the right navigation item to Done in my next when I've selected a row. I tried it, and it's worked. But it's breaking however, because the function which implements the doneEditing body, is only in the next view controller, any help will be really appreciated. This is my code:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "editContact" {

            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            let destinationVC: NewCategoryViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NewCategoryViewController
            let contact:Contact = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as! Contact
            destinationVC.contact = contact
            var rightAddBarButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "doneEditing:")
            destinationVC.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightAddBarButtonItem
        }
    }
```

and my next view controller is :

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


class NewCategoryViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var contact: Contact? = nil

// initialize the core data context:
let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

// MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var imageHolder: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var phoneField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var categoryField: UITextField!

// MARK: - Actions
@IBAction func savebtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: context!)
    let newContact = Contact(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        newContact.name = nameField.text
        newContact.email = emailField.text
        newContact.phone = phoneField.text
        //newContact.photo = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageHolder.image, 1)

    var error: NSError?

    context?.save(&error)

    if let errorSaving = error {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Couldn't save contact !!!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        nameField.text = ""
        emailField.text = ""
        phoneField.text = ""
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message: "Contact added", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = contact?.name

    if contact != nil {
        nameField.text = contact?.name
        emailField.text = contact?.email
        phoneField.text = contact?.phone

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func doneEditing() {

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change target from self to destinationVC.

Use this:

```
var rightAddBarButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: destinationVC, action: "doneEditing:")
```

`self` should be used when the selector is defined in the same class which makes the call. In this case the selector is in a separate class.

**OR**

I would suggest you to add the right bar button in the viewDidLoad method of NewCategoryViewController. In which case the code will be:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "doneEditing:")
```

**AND**
implement `doneEditing:` method as

```
func doneEditing(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

}
```

Comment: I'm having this error: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19268c80
2015-09-23 15:50:32.013 My People[1635:1036672] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[My_People.NewCategoryViewController doneEditing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19268c80'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: I'm using the same viewcontroller for adding and editing the contact. That's why I'm doing in it in the segue, because when I add, the button will be add, but when i Select a name from the tableview, the button will have to change to done.

Comment: thanks found away. to change it but still it's failing with the mention error

Comment: yes to:  func doneEditing() {
        if contact != nil {
            editContact()
        }
        
        dismissController()
//        else {
        
//        }
    }
    
    func dismissController() {
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
    
    
    func editContact() {
        contact?.name = nameField.text
        contact?.phone = phoneField.text
        contact?.email = emailField.text
//        contact?.photo = imageHolder.image
    }

Comment: @congolesedevelopper you need to add (sender: UIBarButtonItem) parameter in the method definition my friend. :) I hope you are getting what I am trying to say.

Comment: see your doneEditing method does not accept any parameters. It is written like func doneEditing() {

}

but it should be:

func doneEditing(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

}

Comment: thanks got it. have it worked. thanks very much. still have some targets to achieve with pics and colour saving in the core data, giving them ago. really appreciated your help and disponibility